# How do I save jpeg images with no compression in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

How do I save jpeg images with no compression in Matlab?

I tried

```
targetImageFile = 'skype2.png';
targetImage = imread(targetImageFile);

imwrite(targetImage,'output.png','Compression','none',...
       'WriteMode','append');
```

However, I got

```
input:
compressionRatio      = 1.992735e+000
output:
compressionRatio      = 2.090858e+000
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: can I ask how you got/computed the compression ratio? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unclear whether you are trying to save your image in [JPEG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720264) or [PNG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-742371) format (your question and code sample each use something different), but if you look at the documentation for [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) you will notice that neither of those formats uses a `'Compression'` or `'WriteMode'` parameter. The [TIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720267) and [HDF4](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-730061) formats use those two parameters.

For [JPEG format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720264), you can adjust the `'Mode'` or `'Quality'` properties to reduce compression of the image. [PNG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) uses lossless compression. If you want to avoid *all* compression (lossy or lossless), you may as well just save your image in BMP format.

Here are a few examples of saving an image in different formats and the resulting file size of the output image:

```
X = imread('peppers.png');             %# Sample image: 589,824 bytes of data
imwrite(X,'peppers.bmp');             %# Bitmap output: 589,878 byte output file
imwrite(X,'peppers.png');     %# PNG output (lossless): 287,589 byte output file
imwrite(X,'peppers.jpg');       %# JPEG output (lossy):  23,509 byte output file
imwrite(X,'peppers.jpg',...     %# JPEG output (lossy): 144,068 byte output file
          'Quality',100);
imwrite(X,'peppers.jpg',...  %# JPEG output (lossless): 306,061 byte output file
          'Mode','lossless');
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want no compression, then surely you want a bitmap (`'bmp'`)? If you want lossless compression, then you want `'mode'` to be `'lossless'` for `'jpg'`. `'png'` is already a lossless format.

`'Compression'` is only an option for the `'tiff'` format.

See, http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-713936