# Matrix content is changed when saved as image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encryption

I did some encryption technique which encrypted the image LENA.jpg.I saved it as a encrypted image.When I am reading the same matrix for decription process I noticed a change in the values of the matrix.Image has lost some of its characteristics.When I decrypted the Matrix (encrypted) without saving as picture the output is perfect..But Once saved it loses its quality...Why it is happening...

I am attaching the decrypted image..you can see some pixels missing clearly..
[image: decrypted image]

Answer (score 2):

When you "save as picture" what format are you using? Some are lossy but it sounds like you need a lossless format for this.

Comment: jpg is lossy. Try png, bmp, gif, or tif.

Comment: Is there any **lossless jpeg** format.How to save in **lossless jpeg** format

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is aptly explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907960/1492106) SO answer.

If you had saved the image in a `.jpg` format, it is to be expected. JPEG is by default a lossy format. It does have some lossless variants though.

Comment: ok thanksss..i will go with png